# Fail test if element have text inside element on the table

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Hello This is my first question and I hope that someone will help me :)

I would like to check if on the table exist item with text. If exist I want to fail test.

```
internal static bool IsElementWithTextInCollection(ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> table, string customerFieldName)
{
    foreach (var item in table)
    {
        if (item.Text.(customerFieldName))
        {

        }
    }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: What test? I see no referencing of any Unit Test frameworks here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the text Contains in your item give false to your result and break the loop.

```
internal static bool IsElementWithTextInCollection(
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> table, string customerFieldName)
{        
    bool result = true;
    foreach (var item in table)
    {
        if (item.Text.Contains(customerFieldName))
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Just as a key note for OP, you could bring this down to 1 line `return table.Any(p => p.Text.Contains(customerFieldName))`

Comment: @ColinM yep but I'm using the structure of the op.